# react-native-maps undefined is not an object (evaluating 'PropTypes.string')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

We have a small hackaton in our office and I have some problem with `react-native-maps`. I am getting error: **undefined is not an object (evaluating 'PropTypes.string')** which is going to MapMaker.js file from MapView.

There is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "niehandlowa",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.3.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "16.3.0-alpha.3",
    "react-native": "^0.54.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.30",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I will be glad because today our team want to finish great app that we started yesterday :)

Have a nice day everybody!

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely related to the version of `react-native-maps` you are using. [`v0.4.2`](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/5a2ad20477e82fb7a869850fedfabfb4d2a38732/components/MapMarker.js#L5) is using `PropTypes` from `react` and the [library separated now](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types). You should use a more resent version of the [`react-native-maps` library](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/tree/master)